# Error: File '' couldn't be removed (error 2: No such file or directory)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-1.18

I get the following pgAdmin III error every time I restore a database, using  pgAdmin III:

```
Error: File '' couldn't be removed (error 2: No such file or directory)
```

See the [pgadmin log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12210605/).

My configuration:

> PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu
>   4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit
>
> Linux 3.19.0-26-generic #28~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 12 14:09:17 UTC
>   2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Can you try performing the same task using the `pgsql` and/or `pg_restore` command line tools? The reason is that they frequently give more detailled and informative error messages than GUI tools. From your pasted log, you appear (or pgAdmin does) to be trying to delete a file with no name. Have you checked the PostgreSQL log? I normally start my server with "./bin/pg_ctl -D ./data/ -l logfile start" - anything in your equivalent of logfile? Maybe try [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime-config-logging.html) for verbose logging?

Comment: @Vérace i used pgsql and pg_restore didn't get any error. i then changed to a lower version of PGADMIN3 1.18 still didn't get any error. i then built the new version 1.22.0 Alpha 2 from the git repository. this also has no error. i guess the problem is limited to only  pgAdmin III Version 1.20.0.

Comment: Sometimes happens @byarufaf - maybe you could report it to the pgAdmin people? I know that the PostgreSQL project generally produces software of great quality and they would want to iron out any bugs! BTW, you do know that alpha means just that - i.e. not production ready?

Comment: @Vérace i guess the bug was fixed in the alpha, So need to report it. but this PgAdmin is for personal use not production so im okay using the Alpha until the new version is released officially.

Comment: the same issue here with 1.22.0 version.

Comment: Installed PgAdmin4 in Ubuntu with Pyhoton3 and virtualenv from here `https://askubuntu.com/questions/831262/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-in-desktop-mode-on-ubuntu/831263#comment1669389_831263`

Answer (score 4):

[This bug was reported by Byaruhanga Franklin to the mailing lists,](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CABRSzGN1C470z3T%2BrJntpnq2P9PtpkREgZsPOSxvULT4y5tzZA%40mail.gmail.com)

> I also tried with pgsql and pg_restore didn't get any error. i then changed to a lower version of PGADMIN3 1.18 still didn't get any error. i then built the new version 1.22.0 Alpha 2 from the git repository. this also has no error. i guess the **problem is limited to only pgAdmin III Version 1.20.0.**

Upgrade to PgAdmin3 1.22, or to PgAdmin4.

Comment: Using vesrion 1.22.0 (Jan 12, 2016, rev: REL-1_22_0) and having same problem.

Comment: @GeorgyIvanov file another bug, guess they didn't resolve it right. =(

Comment: Same problem 1.22.0